# Include pyinvoke tasks from collection definitions in multiple directroies

Tags: python, pyinvoke

I have a monorepo and I want to have tasks at different levels (in the directory tree).

When I run [pyinvoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org/) at a deeper level, I want to have access to the tasks in the higher levels + the tasks in the current level. They can (should) be in different namespaces.

i.e.

```
repo_top-|
         |_ tasks-|
         |        |_ __init__.py
         |        |_ install
         |_apps-|
                |_ tasks-|
                |        |_ __init__.py
                         |_ lambdas
```

If I am in the repo_top/apps directory (or lower) I should be able to say

```
invoke --list
```

and see a listing of the tasks in `repo_top/tasks` AND `repo_top/apps/tasks`

I have it so

- I see the top level stuff if I am in the top level or any sub level that does not have its own tasks module

```
inv --list
Available tasks:

  install.bootstrap-devx
```

- I see the apps tasks if I am in the apps directory or lower.

```
inv --list
Available tasks:

  lambdas.python-build-lambda
```

I've tried a few things but so far have not figured out how to make it so I see all the tasks if I am in the apps directory or lower.

What I want to see if I execute it in `repo_top/apps` is something like:

```
inv --list
Available tasks:

  install.bootstrap-devx
  lambdas.python-build-lambda
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find a "hack" to make this work.

Create symbolic link to a unique file name at the higher levels

```
repo_top/
├── tasks/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── install.py
├── top_tasks (symbolic link to tasks)
└── apps/
    └── tasks/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── lambdas.py
```

In apps/tasks/lambdas.py (or any pyinvoke module including `__init__py`) you can do something like:

```
project_top_dir = Path(__file__).parents[2]
sys.path.append(str(project_top_dir))
from top_tasks.utils import *
```

And all the modules in the top level `tasks` directory will be available to that module. You could also do a more specific import other than `*`

You can do this in deeper trees as well if you want.